# How to transpose row value as column in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure is like this:

[image]

But I want output as follows:

```
English  hindi  telugu  drawing
-------  ----- ------- --------
english  hindi  telugu  drawing
paper2   paper1  paper2  drawing2
```

I want to display `subjectid` as column headings and `paper names` as rows.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a query like the following one if classid does not matter.

```
SELECT [English], [Hindi],[Telugu],[Drawing]
FROM 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubjectId ORDER BY PaperName) AS rownum, SubjectId, PaperName 
   FROM T
   GROUP BY SubjectId, PaperName 
)AS base
PIVOT
( MAX(PaperName) FOR SubjectId IN ([English], [Hindi],[Telugu],[Drawing])) AS pvt;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your responce. but My Subject ids are not fixed.